# Pythonic way to design a list-like API

Tags: python

I have written an API that looks and feels like a list of strings, yet calls a function whenever an item is added or removed from the list. A good example for what I mean is promotion codes for a cart: you'd only use them as strings, while under the hood the respective promotion is added to the cart by calling some commerce service. Here's an example:

```
class Cart:
    def __init__(self):
        self.promotions = RepresentationalList(self.__apply_promotion_code, self.__remove_promotion_code)

    def __apply_promotion_code(self, promo_code):
        print(f"Adding promo code {promo_code} ...")
        # ... call API to add promo code ...
        result = id(promo_code) # do this for now
        return result

    def __remove_promotion_code(self, promo_code):
        print(f"Removing promo code {promo_code} ...")
        # ... call API to remove promo code

cart = Cart()
cart.promotions += ["HAM", "SPAM", "EGGS"]
print(cart.promotions) # ['FOO', 'SPAM', 'EGGS']
assert "SPAM" in cart.promotions
assert cart.promotions[1] == "SPAM"
cart.promotions.remove("SPAM")
assert "SPAM" not in cart.promotions
assert cart.promotions == ["HAM", "EGGS"]
cart.promotions.clear()
assert len(cart.promotions) == 0
assert cart.promotions == []
```

That `RepresentationalList` (is there a better name?) is what allows this behaviour; it takes the `transform` and `revert` functions as arguments when you instantiate it. This is the implementation:

```
class RepresentationalList():
    def __init__(self, transform_fn, revert_fn, keys=[]):
        self.transform = transform_fn
        self.revert = revert_fn
        self.data = [(key, self.transform(key)) for key in keys]
        
    def append(self, key):
        self.data.append((key, self.transform(key)))
        
    def remove(self, key):
        self.revert(key)
        self.data = [item for item in self.data if item[0] != key]

    def clear(self):
        for item in self.data:
            self.revert(item[0])            
        self.data.clear()

    def __iadd__(self, keys):
        self.data += [(key, self.transform(key)) for key in keys]
        return self

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.data[i][0]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.__str__()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str([item[0] for item in self.data])

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, RepresentationalList):
            return self.data == other.data
        elif isinstance(other, list):
            return [item[0] for item in self.data] == other
        else:
            return False
```

Now here's the thing: while `RepresentationalList` does what I want it do and is reusable as well, I'm wondering whether I'm missing some pythonic way to achieve all of this. Subclassing `list`, decorators ... I don't know. I'm new to Python and would love grok the principles of Python. Thanks!

Comment: You can certainly derive from `list`, but for the application you identified (cart in a web site), you wouldn't do this way.  You would have a `Cart` object that CONTAINED a list, and added methods to manage the items in the list appropriately.  In that situation, the list is actually going to be a database table, not something in memory.

Comment: Absolutely, Tim – the actual list of promotions would be server-side. This little API will not be used anywhere in production, though, it's more my personal "tooling" API for daily tasks, automation etc.

Answer (score 0):

I won't tell you what is the pythonic way to implement this because although there are some famous conventions for doing stuff in python, for the most part the word "pythonic" can be subjective. I will point out some small changes you could make to "improve" your implementation (in case you are interested in a feedback).

1. `def __init__(self, transform_fn, revert_fn, keys=[]):`. Don't use mutable objects as function default. This will have unexpected results as the default will be used by multiple instances. Instead you should do this:

   ```py
   def __init__(self, transform_fn, revert_fn, keys=None):
       if keys is None:
           keys = []  # this creates a new list for each instance of the class
   ```
2. ```py
   def __repr__(self) -> str:
       return self.__str__()

   def __str__(self) -> str:
       return str([item[0] for item in self.data])
   ```

   If you want to implement the same method for `__str__` and `__repr__`, you can implement `__repr__` only and `__str__` will default to it.
3. ```py
   def __eq__(self, other):
       if isinstance(other, RepresentationalList):
           return self.data == other.data
       elif isinstance(other, list):
           return [item[0] for item in self.data] == other
       else:
           return False
   ```

   There a standard way to define the comparison magic methods in python including `__eq__`, `__neq__`, etc. that is to return `NotImplemented` for other types. Also lists are expensive (as in memory expensive), try to avoid creating them if they are not needed. The method then looks like this:

   ```py
   def __eq__(self, other):
       if isinstance(other, RepresentationalList):
           return self.data == other.data
       elif isinstance(other, list):
           # return [item[0] for item in self.data] == other
           # the previous line becomes:
           return all(x == y for x, y in zip(self.data, other))
       else:
           return NotImplemented
   ```
4. ```py
   def __getitem__(self, i):
       return self.data[i][0]
   ```

   This does not work with *slices* (i.e. if you do something like `l[1:5]`)

A general comment: The `RepresentationalList` feels more like a `dict` than a `list` (dicts are like hash maps in other languages).

Comment: Thanks so much for those suggestions! It's the little details that make an implementation more robust. :)

Comment: I realized the equality check needed a little tweak because `zip` stops when one of the sequences ends: `return len(self.data) == len(other) and all(entry[0] == key_other for entry, key_other in zip(self.data, other))`